# How to reload modules used in the REPL?

Tags: raku

The question is pretty self explanatory. If I load a module in the REPL during development I would like to pick up changes without having to `exit` first.

Comment: You are asking the REPL to perform IDE-like functions.  Perhaps you should look at using [Comma](https://commaide.com).  Because that's an IDE made specifically for Perl 6, and has the feature you are asking for here.  And then some :-)

Comment: No I don't ask for IDE functionality, really. I am looking for something like Ruby's `load` or Pythons `execfile` maybe?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `EVALFILE`
(With some caveats)

**lib/example.pm6**

```perl6
say (^256).pick.fmt('%02X')
```

**REPL**

```perl6
> EVALFILE('lib/example.pm6'); # rather than `use lib 'lib'; use example;`
DE
> EVALFILE('lib/example.pm6');
6F
```

---

The problem comes when you try to use a namespace.

**lib/example.pm6**

```perl6
class Foo {
  say (^256).pick.fmt('%02X')
}
```

**REPL**

```perl6
> EVALFILE('lib/example.pm6')
C0
> EVALFILE('lib/example.pm6')
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/brad/EVAL_2
Redeclaration of symbol 'Foo'
at /home/brad/EVAL_2:1
------> class Foo⏏ {
    expecting any of:
        generic role
```

This still doesn't work if you change the `:ver` part of the name between each time you load it.

**lib/example.pm6**

```perl6
class Foo:ver(0.001) {
  say (^256).pick.fmt('%02X')
}
```

---

One way to get around this if you are just experimenting is to make them lexical rather than global.

**lib/example.pm6**

```perl6
my class Foo {  # default is `our`
  say (^256).pick.fmt('%02X')
}
```

**REPL**

```perl6
> EVALFILE('lib/test.pm6')
DD
> EVALFILE('lib/test.pm6')
88
> EVALFILE('lib/test.pm6')
6E
```

It has a separate lexical scope though:

```perl6
> Foo
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Undeclared name:
    Foo used at line 1
```

So you will want to alias it:

```perl6
> my \Foo = EVALFILE('lib/test.pm6'); # store a ref to it in THIS lexical scope
0C
> Foo
(Foo)

> my \Foo = EVALFILE('lib/test.pm6'); # still works the second time
F7
```

This of course only works because the class definition is the last statement in that scope.

---

There may be a way to cause a reload similar to how you can in Perl 5 if you dig into the structure of Rakudo, but as far as I know this is not available as part of the language.

Comment: How to use variables defined in `lib/example.pm6` ?

Comment: @tinmarino You could probably have the last value in the file be a list like: `($foo,$bar,Foo)`, and then deconstruct it when you use it like: `my ($foo,$bar,\Foo) = EVALFILE('lib/test.pm6')`

Answer (score -2):

Like Python's import, you can use the `use` keyword:

```
> perl6
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> use Cro::HTTP::Client
Nil
> my $resp = await Cro::HTTP::Client.get('https://www.perl6.org/');
Cro::HTTP::Response.new(request => Cro::HTTP::Request, status => 200, body-parser-selector => Cro::HTTP::BodyParserSelector::ResponseDefault, body-serializer-selector => Cro::HTTP::BodySerializerSelector::ResponseDefault, http-version => "1.1", http2-stream-id => Int)
> say await $resp.body
```

For more information, https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#Exporting_and_selective_importing may be help.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to **re**load a module after changes to the module without having to exit and reload the REPL.

Comment: @raiph Probably.  I also wander how to reload module in REPL without exit first. Python's REPL should do this, as far as i know.